# Hierarchy in log4j2 does not work as I expected

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Below are a class and the log4j configuration:

$ vi My.java

```
public class My {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("foo.bar"); 
      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.trace("My trace");
        logger.debug("My debug");
        logger.info("My info");
        logger.warn("My warn");
        logger.error("My error");
...
```

$ vi log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="system_out">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %c : %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="foo" fileName="logs/foo.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %c : %m%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="foo.bar" fileName="logs/foo.bar.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %c : %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="foo" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="foo" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="foo.bar" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="foo.bar" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In logs/foo.bar.log appears `warn` and `error` messsages. This is what I expected. But in logs/foo.log  appears nothing, and I expected `info` messages there. Also on the console nothing appears, but I expected `debug` messages. So it does not work as I expected. So what is my mistake?

Also, the argument of LogManager.getLogger must be a name of a logger. But I also see examples where the argument is a class. How does that work, because  when I do that only the root logger does log messages.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of inheritance in Log4j2:

- inheritance of logger configuration, aka "logger hierarchy" that will cause a logger named "foo.bar.baz" to use the configuration of its **nearest** ancestor ("foo.bar"). Your "foo.bar" logger uses the configuration you gave it explicitly.
- inheritance of appenders, aka "additivity" that will cause a logger config to inherit all of its parent's appenders, unless you use `additivity="false"`. In your case the "foo.bar" configuration does not use the appenders of the "foo" configuration.

Another problem with your configuration is that the level of the "foo.bar" logger is set to `WARN`, so it will never send any logging event with a level different from `WARN` and `ERROR`. If you don't want to limit the logger itself, but the appender, you can set `level="WARN"` on the `<AppenderRef>`.

If your purpose is to split different log levels into different log files, you can use a mix of `level` settings (basically a threshold filter) and [`LevelMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/LevelMatchFilter.html)s (or a [`RoutingAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender)):

```xml
<Logger name="foo.bar" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="foo.bar" level="WARN" />
  <AppenderRef ref="foo">
    <LevelMatchFilter level="INFO" />
  </AppenderRef>
  <AppenderRef ref="console">
    <LevelMatchFilter level="DEBUG" />
  </AppenderRef>
</Logger>
```